# Wordpress 404 Error while submiting form

Tags: wordpress, url

In some cases wordpress throws 404 page not found error after submitting page(uses template) with form but if we hit the URL by copying, Page loads. What may be the reason?

for eg. 
I have form in **www.example.com/contact** and there is a form with action  **www.example.com/thankyou**

when i submit form, **www.example.com/thankyou** fires 404 Error, but when i paste **www.example.com/thankyou** to address bar and press enter page opens. Why

Comment: press F12 to see inner exception. or in the developer tools click the network tab to see what happen.

Comment: The problem is most likely that the form has the wrong `action` set. Why this is or how to fix it will at least require us to see the HTML of the `<form>` element and likely the PHP that builds the form.

Comment: What field names are you using in the form?

Comment: full_name,address,email,suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add the http:// in action so your new action will be :
http://www.example.com/thankyou then it will works .
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Hello I found the solution. ..this issue was because of name of form elements such textbox, radio etc. I named a textbox name suggestions and same name was used for custom post type.  So I came to know that form control names should be unique and should not match with the post type name or category slug. Thanks